# Package a .jar into a single .exe alongside the needed JRE

Tags: java, windows, jar, exe, launch4j

I was wondering how I could package my .jar into a single clickable .exe file, that contains all java related stuff to run, dropping the need for installing JRE.
The solution I found was to do it using launch4j and having the .exe inside a folder with the JRE but I was wondering whether I could just bundle the JRE into the .exe witout the need to have it in the same folder as the JRE needed.

Comment: I think exe4j can bundle your jar and a JRE, I haven't used it for a will though

Comment: No need for [3rd party](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9)